# How to Clone an unapproved github pull request

Tags: github

Thank you for the time first and foremost.

I have a pull request on Github which isn't merged yet.

(Let's call it a branch name: `myFeatureBranch`)

I don't want to add any changes on top of it, I want to clone the pull request, make changes and push it as a *new* PR (*and close the current Pull request*)

I'm trying to figure out how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new branch on top of `myFeatureBranch` and do whatever changes you need to do. If you then open a new PR with your new branch, it will be completely independent of the existing PR (but also include the features of that branch).

Comment: thank you. Just so i understand, you're suggesting I do `git checkout -b myFeaturev2 origin/myFeatureBranch ` ? @PMF

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the command line, but I think yes, that's it.